# Laptop connecting to only one WiFi network and not connecting to other available WiFi networks

Tags: wifi

I just installed Linux Mint 19 (Tara) on my HP laptop and everything works amazing, however I can't seem to get it to connect to my WiFi network. All my other computers can get access, plus, before when the laptop has Windows XP, it could also find and connect. Is there a way to check if it's even detecting the correct network? If so, how would I set up a proper connection to the network?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try in the terminal

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`

and check if your wifi adapter sees the WIFI network you want to connect to? If you are in a congested area with multiple wifi networks, you can use `iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -i ssid` and look for the name of your WIFI network in this much shorter list.

`wlan0` being the name of your wireless adapter. `iwconfig` will list the appropriate one if it is not wlan0.

If you find yourself unable to even scan for nearby networks then this will likely become a question about setting up your wireless adapter, as opposed to deciphering why you might not be able to connect to one particular WIFI network.